# Best practice to develop a separate front-end for my API?

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-boot, frontend

I have a Back-end web application that provides me with custom API endpoints (Java - Spring). I like to keep everything separate. one API application that provides everything else remotely. My question is: What is the best practice to start a new Front-end project that connects to my API?

Requirements:

- The Front-end project should be on a different server
- The Front-end project should support routing, meaning I will have full control regarding the /paths. so no .extensions at the end.
- SEO is very important in this specific case.

My preference is to go with React.js but I have doubts regarding SEO because the project I want to migrate from is WordPress (up and running with a good SEO performance).

I wish that I can find a simple solution with pure HTML, CSS and some kind of JavaScript.

Thank you.

Comment: If you know React then you can use framework called `Next Js`. 
If you are `Vue Js` fan then you can use `Nuxt Js`. 

They both are made for `ssr ( Server side rendering)` . You won't have any issue in SEO.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to select React.js, I think it's my best choice. Hope It's not affecting SEO negatively.

Comment: You need to use Next JS then :)

Answer (score 1):

React isn't actually bad for SEO. So long as you're taking the proper steps to ensure that the page load time isn't bad. If the site that you're migrating is massive, make sure you're lazy loading.

If you have doubts that Google or other search engines will render the js, then I suggest going with [Nextjs](https://nextjs.org/docs) like Rakesh K mentioned.

There's also nothing wrong with recreating the site with a templating language like [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/), then rendering it on an Express server, or whatever suits you. Just including this option in case you don't know React, and don't want to have to learn it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'll navigate NextJs and Handlebars to figure out which one is better for my scenario. keep the good work.